# «Отгрохать огромный дом» — тавтология?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, тавтология

*...ей мой шеф хорошо платит, да и дети у Нины Сеергеевны состоятельные, **огромный дом ей отгрохали**, обеспечивают всем необходимым и даже излишним.*
[А.Маринина. Личные мотивы](http://knijky.ru/books/lichnye-motivy?page=13)

*Необходимость скрываться от ОБХСС отпала, Константин **отгрохал огромный дом**, превратил старую дачу в домик для гостей, обзавёлся парком автомобилей...*
[Д. Донцова. Фея с золотыми зубами](https://books.google.ee/books?id=3OpUtWj_m6UC&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=TX2teR4lGU&sig=72u0tF0tatGhv9Z4iZn9jVjn-u0&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi48qfnr9nTAhWlJZoKHQGkBKkQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8&f=false)

"Иссомневалась вся": является ли фраза *отгрохать огромный дом* тавтологичной?
Или чем-то другим? Буду благодарна за разъяснения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Из Малого академического словаря:

> ОТГРО́ХАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; сов.
>
> 1. Разг. Перестать грохать, издавать шум, грохот. Пушки отгрохали.
> 2. перех. Прост. **Построить, сделать, организовать что-л. *большое*, внушительное по размерам, стоимости и т. п.** — Зернохранилище
>      отгрохали, на будущий год овцеводческую ферму заводить думают.
>      Чаковский, У нас уже утро.

Думаю, что имеет смысл дать более развернутый ответ и пояснить, что, собственно, такое плеоназм.

Плеоназм — это разновидность амплификации; стилистическая фигура, основанная на избыточности словесного выражения смысла высказывания, которая проявляется в семантическом дублировании его частей (нередко с помощью синонимических или, по крайней мере, семантически однопорядковых слов, средств выразительности — эпитетов, гипербол...).

По-моему, очевидно, что в семантике глагола "отгрохать" присутствует элемент масштабности. Она — эта масштабность — может быть связана с размером, со стоимостью и т. д. Словарная статья, приведенная выше,  подтверждает такую идею.

Рассмотрим словосочетание "отгрохать дом" в сравнении с нейтральным "построить дом". Есть ли разница? Конечно. Отгрохать дом — не просто построить, а построить что-то внушительное, может быть даже роскошное.

> В одном месте над дорогой стоял невиданной красоты терем с резными наличниками, коньками на крыше: какой-то начальник нашел умельца-плотника и тот **отгрохал ему такой дом**! [И. М. Дьяконов. Книга воспоминаний. Часть вторая. Глава четвертая (1942-1944) (1995)]

Теперь перейдем к словосочетанию "отгрохать огромный дом". Чем оно отличается от "отгрохать дом"? Тем, что в нем уточняется, в чем именно проявляется масштабность, — в размере. Вот это уточнение можно считать амплификацией, т. е. распространением.

Вообще, одной из основных стилистических функций плеоназма является предельная конкретизация описаний, картин, характеристик. Говоря, что словосочетание содержит плеоназм, я имел в виду именно то, что в нем присутствует этот элемент конкретизации.

Другой вопрос, присутствует ли в этом выражении излишность, необходимая для плеоназма; иными словами, есть ли в нем вышеупомянутая предельность. Мне кажется, что да.

Comment: Из ответа в этой теме Aer: "Корректно: отгрохать дом (это уже значит, что дом большой)". Нет, не уже значит. См. пример: "... рубил, пилил и скоро отгрохал дом. Не то чтобы большой, но видный". Да и в этом примере вряд ли слово "отгрохал" говорит о больших размерах строения — скорее, о его красоте: 
"В одном месте над дорогой стоял невиданной красоты терем с резными наличниками, коньками на крыше: какой-то начальник нашел умельца-плотника и тот отгрохал ему такой дом!"

Comment: Если дом огромен - нужно явно это указать. (1) Об обычном доме тоже можно сказать "отгрохать", обычный дом - это тоже что-то большое, а его строительство требует больших усилий и средств. (2) Из словарной статьи следует, что "отгроханный" дом может быть "внушительным по стоимости" (скажем, дом построен из дорогих материалов, художественно оформлен), а не обязательно обладать большими размерами.

Comment: @М_Г не очень понятная ваша мысль по поводу "отгрохать обычный дом". Такое сочетание как раз очень маловероятно, так как глагол "отгрохать" и нужен для ухода от этой "обычности".

Comment: Построить дом, даже самый обычный, - маленькой подвиг с точки зрения простого человека, поэтому "Я отгрохал себе дом" может быть сказано даже если дом - обычный.

Comment: @М_Г а, понятно. Ну, это не совсем в тему (если уж на то пошло, для представителя племени тумба-юмба сложенное из бетонных блоков коробкообразное здание 3 на 4 может казаться шедевром архитектуры). То есть дело не в том, что считать роскошным, большим, необычным и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, конечно, нет ни явного, ни даже скрытого плеоназма, хотя слабую тавтологию найти можно.

Причина ваших сомнений, как я понимаю, в некоторой общности понятийных полей слов "отгрохать" (построить, создать нечто очень большое) и "огромный". Так вот, для признания плеоназмом этого совершенно недостаточно, необходимо, чтобы такой повтор значения был бы очевидно излишним, не несущим никакого дополнительного смысла. Здесь это не так, основной смысл глагола все-таки - не "большой", а "построить", а без "огромный" не ясно, что он именно "огромный", а не просто большой.

Вот в отношении тавтологии - да есть, как риторическая фигура, в данном случае, полагаю, вполне стилистически уместная. Уместность её я вывожу из того, что субъективно не вызывает она отторжения, а любые замены на варианты с меньшей тавтологичностью ("воздвигнуть огромный дом" или там "отгрохать грандиозный дом") или ничего не добавляют, или выглядят неестественными. Зато выразительность в "отгрохал огромный дом" очень даже присутствует.

Вот несколько подобных примеров со слабой или косвенной тавтологичностью (разных типов), которые совсем не считаются ошибочными: ***"писать письмо", "рожденный от [таких-то] родителей", "досужие забавы", "во веки веков"*** - ну и много еще можно придумать.

Answer (score 1):

В выражении "отгрохать огромный дом" слово *отгрохать* не является точным просторечным синонимом слова "построить". Большей частью оно определённым образом характеризует процесс строительства: строили с удалью, с размахом, быстро, возможно, помпезно и т. п. Масштабы строительства здесь важны постольку, поскольку определённого уровня организацию процесса либо сложно представить на скромном объекте, либо она будет выглядеть там не совсем уместной. А если огромный дом строился кирпичик за кирпичиком многолетним кропотливым трудом, вряд ли свидетели строительства скажут, что его *отгрохали*.

Я не считаю, что в рассматриваемом выражении присутствует плеоназм или тавтология в масштабах, достаточных для признания его речевой ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо, Медведик (я помню — Вы не были против).

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, ни тавтологией, ни даже плеоназмом не является. Надо же учитывать и эмоциональную составляющую, и лексическую сочетаемость, и традиции употребления, а "отгрохать дом" – так практически не говорят, так что ни о какой "корректности" и речи нет. Ведь плеоназм – это не просто избыточность, это нежелательная избыточность. Избыточностей в языке – пруд пруди, и с ними никто и не думает бороться (яркий пример: "видел своими собственными глазами" – плеоназм? Будем последовательно искоренять и получим в конце концов совершенно безликое "видел"; практически то же и с отгроханным огромным домом).

Comment: Жаль, Корпус пока не хочет работать, но с "отгрохать дом" вы погорячились — очень даже говорят. Уже в Гугле на первой странице...

Comment: И еще: плеоназм может быть как примером речевой ошибки, так и стилистическим оборотом. Так что "ни тавтологией, ни даже плеоназмом не является" — не точно.

Comment: Но вы же как раз и посчитали "отгрохать огромный дом"  речевой ошибкой, что неверно.

Comment: Ну, я так считаю (и привел аргументы) — вы пока не доказали, что я не прав. Кстати говоря, мной упомянут и другой возможный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно при слове "отгрохал" имеют в виду размер дома. Но оно может подразумевать и его красивую отделку. Здесь нет ни тавтологии, ни плеоназма. Мое мнение таково.